# Calculate hours worked since 12am

Tags: time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to calculate hours worked since 12AM on a time card.  I have tried multiple things but nothing returning the value I need.  The sheet provided is only an example of what I am trying to achieve, the SUM formula should remain there because on the actual time card I am using more than one row.

I am currently using the following formula to show hours worked since 12 AM

`=LEFT(A2,1)`

Which yes is giving me the number but, it won't let me sum it.  I feel there has to be another way to get the hours since 12AM, just nothing I am trying or finding is getting me the result I am looking for.

[Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HY_Eidm4KrA8b0Kv_8BYnzQBLXsku2s_4Se8DXZo_gc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The first field with the 2:00:00 have to be a date field; then you can calculate (A1 - 00:00:00 AM ), you'l find good examples here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257514/how-to-delete-the-rest-of-each-line-after-a-certain-pattern-or-a-string-in-a-fil

Comment: there has to be a way to do it without a date. On the actual time card I already have a date column, when I let people use this I don't want them to have to enter a date and time.  I am just trying to get the difference between 12am and 2am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so by setting 12 am in an isolated cell I was able to just subtract 12AM from the time out and multiply it by 24, which gives me the number I was looking for.

This is in B2

`=(A2-D10)*24`

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
=(A2-"00:00:00")*24
```

[image: 0]